# How to earn Bitcoin without any investment

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I have read about something that selling the computing power but I don't think it gives its value. Are there any more simple methods??

Comment: stealing???????

Comment: You need to create "wealth" for the community and community will make you rich. (http://paulgraham.com/wealth.html) Go code!

Answer (score 2):

You always invest something (time for services, money for compute power, ...) when you want get something so the question does not make that much sense. "There is no free lunch."

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for playing around, you might look for bitcoin faucets.

If it is for more, then you might look at "https://www.udemy.com/beginners-blueprint-for-earning-bitcoins-online/".

If it is for getting started, and you intend to contribute, look at the code, look at "bitcoin.org", and provide a service to the community :-)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you always have to invest something, even if it is just your time, but there certainly are ways to earn bitcoin without any monetary investment.

Here are the 3 sites I use to get all the info I need for this exact question...

http://www.gr1innovations.com/how-to-make-money-with-bitcoin.html

http://earn-bitcoins.com

https://99bitcoins.com/how-to-earn-bitcoins-fast-free/

A lot of if is the same/similar on each one, but it's definitely some great ideas for earning bitcoins.